# HTML div overlapping content with div below. HTML CSS Begineer

Tags: css, html

I am new to HTML and CSS coding. I am trying to code a web layout in HTML & CSS. As I am new to HTML & CSS the code structure is not intitutive and neat.

I have attached a screenshot showing the problem. All the internal divs are relative to the main_container div and thus internal div's has a top attribute for example top:100px; etc.

The problem is that whenever I insert more content inside a top div then the content overlaps with content in the div below. Can anybody improve the code structure so that it is more flexible and reposition the div's below whenever content is inserted in the top div.

Here is the [ZIP](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/27899629/new-layout.zip) file containing html, css & img files.

[Screenshot Link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/27899629/overlapping%20content.png)

I hope I am explained my problem clearly.

thanks & regards,
dkjain.

Comment: Its best to post your problem code, I don't think many will download your zip file.  I am sure you have the best intentions but the potential of "sharing" a virus is there with a downloadable file.  Alternatively you can supply a URL link to your code.

Comment: yup you are right. Be assured that file is just html,css and img stuff no js, exe etc. actually i wanted anyone to recreate the problem so I just uploaded the ZIP. I do my dev locally and don't use a testing server so no link.

Answer (score 1):

Clear your DIV using CSS:

```
.clear{clear:both}
```

And for the HTML:

```
<div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
```

Use this between the DIVs that are overlapping.

Comment: Hy your reply applies is general but plz take a look at my code (zipfile). The elements are relative to the main_container div and the inner divs are then positioned absolute to the main_container by specifying a fixed distance from the main_container for eg:<div id="main_container" style="position:relative;"> <div id="inner-div1" top:40px; position:absolute;></div><div id="inner-div2" top:80px; position:absolute;></div></div>. The problem is when I add content in inner-div1 and if content goes 80px more from absolute_container, the content overflows inner_div2. How to resolve this?

Comment: Good answer, and it does seem necessary sometimes to include the non-breaking space otherwise it will fail (not sure under what circumstances exactly).  My question is why does a div *ever* overlap with a preceding div in the first place?  I can understand it if you explicitly forced overlapping (however you might do that), but why would it ever be rendered this way by default?  This is just one of many baffling things about HTML/CSS that make me shake my head and resort to using tables for layout.